# Why do dropped Nan rows reappear when you do a GroupKFold

Tags: pandas

Puzzled as to why when you dropna a row of data it reappears when you do a groupkfold operation

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0) ## row 2 has disappeared

groups = df['RaceId'] ## row 2 has indeed gone from groups indices

X = df[['Dlto', 'Penulto']]

y = df[['FinPos']]

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=2)

for train_index, test_index in gkf.split(X, y, groups=groups):

print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

at this point row 2 (removed Nan) reappears in the train or test index and the last row has not been picked up.

Comment: you need to show us, how your dataframe looks like

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my misunderstanding. I had not remembered that dropna appears to modify indices and not physically remove and shuffle down rows. Once I got this the rest made sense